# Flutter Firebase Storage listAll

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download all videos in firebase storage using .listAll(). In the forEach(), I'm getting the URL when I print the value, but its not adding it to my list. Am I doing something wrong?

```
      final List<String> videoUrls = [];

      final result = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().listAll();

      result.items.forEach((Reference ref){
        ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
          print(value);
          videoUrls.add(value);
        });
      });
```

Comment: instead of `foreach` try to use traditional `for..loop` with `await ref.getDownloadURL()`; I hope this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. In this code snippet, get download URL task is done asynchronously.

```
  final List<String> videoUrls = [];

  final result = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().listAll();

  result.items.forEach((Reference ref) async {
    await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      String val = value.toString();
      print(val);
      videoUrls.add(val);
    });
  });
```

Comment: What's the rationale behind using both `await` and the `then` callback?